# Flanders Red from Brewing Classic Styles

Tags: yeast, fermentation, sour

I am interested in brewing the Flanders red that is found in Brewing Classic Styles. Jamil mentions using the Wyeast 3763 or WLP655 and leaving it sit for a year until the pellicle forms then falls back into the beer. He doesn't mention about racking the beer off of the primary yeast cake. Should you rack your beer off? Is that not the point of the sour mixes? Is it OK to let them sit for a year like that?

I'm just curious because I don't want to waste a year and find out I should have racked it over :-)

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jamil doesn't mention raking off cake in any of those recipes.  He isn't a secondary fermentation type of guy, and my experience tends to find me agreeing with him.

WY3763 Roselare blend is all you need.  Pitch it and wait for it to do its thing.  Racking the beer only stresses the small population of bugs that you'll carry over.  More importantly, racking will introduce too much O2 and will promote acetic acid character to be too high.

Comment: Good call. I understand his no-racking policy, but I thought that was in general for if you are not doing any advanced aging of any sort. Having it sit on the primary yeast for a year got me thinking if this would change.